# Show $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$

Tags: linear-algebra

- Let $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ denote the subset of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ consisting of all $x=(x_1,x_2,...)$ such that $x_i=0$ for all but finitely many values of $i$. Show $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$; find a basis for $\mathbb{R}^\infty$. (Munkres, Analysis on Manifolds, page 10).

My attempt. i) $0\in\mathbb{R}^\infty$, clelar.

ii) Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^\infty$. Then we have clearly $x=(0,0,...)+y=(0,0,...)=(0,0,...)\in\mathbb{R}^\infty$,

iii)Let $c$ be a scalar. Then $cx=c(0,0,...)=(0,...)\in\mathbb{R}^\infty$

Since ''Let $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ denote the subset of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ consisting of all $x=(x_1,x_2,...)$ such that $x_i=0$ for all but finitely many values of $i$'', I thinked that for $x_1=(0,0,...), x_2=(0,0,..)$ etc. I mean $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is a zero space. But I'm not sure. Can you help, can you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ are not only $(0,0,\ldots)$, but $(x_1,\ldots, x_k, 0, 0, \ldots)$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. For example $(a,0,0,\ldots),(a,b,0,0,\ldots),(a,b,c,0,0,\ldots) \in \mathbb{R}^\infty$.

So ii) becomes $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_m, 0,0,\ldots), y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n, 0,0,\ldots)$. Without loss of generality, $m \leq n$ and call $x_i = 0$ for $i = m+1, \ldots,n$. Then $x+y = (x_1+y_1,\ldots,x_n+y_n,0,0,\ldots) \in \mathbb{R}^\infty$.

Similarly, iii) becomes $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_m, 0,0,\ldots), cx = (cx_1, \ldots, cx_m, 0,0,\ldots)$.

Comment: Thanks for answer...